# Чтение недоступных данных из массива и переполнение буфера при записи в этот массив

Tags: c

Хочу отсортировать массив длиной length, которую ввожу с клавиатуры, но выдает предупреждение C6385 об чтении недопустимых значение из массива n: допустимый для чтения обьем равен "length * 4" байт, однако считать можно только "8" байт. Также выдает предупреждение C6386 об переполнении буфера
при записи массива n: допустимый для чтения обьем равен "length * 4" байт, однако считать можно только "8" байт. При выводе елементов отсортированного массива, большенство их не выводится. Обьясните пожалуйста как исправить ошибку в коде.

```
{
    int* n, e, t, length;
    scanf_s("%d", &length);
    n = new int[length];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        n[i] = rand() % 100;
        printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    }
    do 
    {
        t = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= sizeof(*n) / sizeof(n[0]); i++) 
        {
            if (n[i] < n[i - 1]) 
            {
                e = n[i - 1];
                n[i - 1] = n[i];
                n[i] = e;
                t = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (t);
    printf("Sorted array\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(*n) / sizeof(n[0]); i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `int i = 1; i <= sizeof(*n) / sizeof(n[0]); i++` Заменить на `int i = 1; i < length; i++`, в обоих местах. Выражение `sizeof(*n) / sizeof(n[0]) == 4 / 4`, подумайте чему будет равно `4 / 4`?

Comment: Это так часто встречается (попытка найти размер динамического или переданного массива через `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`), что уже пора кому-то написать четкий вопрос-ответ, чтоб закрывать такие вопросы как дубликаты...

Comment: Спасибо. Понял свою ошибку

Answer (score 0):

При выделении памяти массиву в Си/Си++ размер памяти и количество элементов официально компилятор может не хранить. Работать с количеством элементов выделенной памяти отдано на выбор программистов.

В вашем коде количество храниться в `length`. Им и пользуйтесь.

Ошибка у вас с индексами. Они должны быть от `0` до `length-1`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sizeof(*n) / sizeof(n[0]); i++)
```

правильно так :

```
for (int i = 1; i < length ; i++)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.